# Differentiate GA Event for Website and Mobile Separately for Measurement Protocol

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have developed two different applications one web and one mobile. A little about the mobile app. It's a hybrid app developed using Phonegap. And for this reason I have implemented Google Analytics Measurement Protocol. It works fine. When I set `t=screenview` as a part of my payload, it actually send the analytics to my mobile analytics view. Ok good. But this is not where my confusion is. My question is about the `event tracking`. I have website and mobile tracking created under one account. The only way to differentiate the tracking is by setting `t=pageview` for web & `t=screenview` for mobile. Then what about event? If is set `t=event` and POST the payload, is it automatically going to detect from which device the event being generated and eventually show it in my mobile tracking view? Or I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding AppId parameters to the even protocol from the app?

Answer (score 0):

Well I gave a try. And GA automatically tracks the event generated from the mobile into the Mobile Tracking View.